# Getting following error on AWS when peering a new connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-vpc

I am getting the following error when I am peering a new connection on `AWS`, I have saved two `VPC` on the same account, a requester and an accepter, I don't know how to resolve this:

```
Error accepting VPC peering connection request.
You are not authorized to perform this operation. Encoded authorization failure message: FVGQnPmo0uHCfxuS4[token]
```

Comment: That indicates your IAM user doesn't have enough permissions to do the peer.

Answer (score 1):

Your IAM user does not have permissions to accept the peering connection, is the likely reason for this.

You should ensure that your current IAM user has the permission `ec2:AcceptVpcPeeringConnection` to allow this to be resolved.

Additionally if your account is part of an organisation then you might find that there is an SCP (Service Control Policy) that prevents this from occuring.

Comment: yes!! it belongs to a SCP of a organisation that belongs to Couresra

Comment: Right Coursera might have an SCP that is denying the access, you would need to reach out to them if you believe you should have access :)

Comment: No problem glad I could help :)